# Как выбрать/добавить способ загрузки в Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

начал изучать как пользоваться Jenkins. Возник следующий вопрос: в туториале был способ запуска - Launch Agent via Java Web Start, но я у себя такого параметра не нашел, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно его добавить? На компьютере JDK есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

изменили этот текст.

в [коммите от 22 апреля](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/c5c803711#diff-bbf561de8607409530a7530e29e2f10e).

было: `Launch agent via Java Web Start`
стало: `Launch agent by connecting it to the master`

---

предваряя следующий вопрос:

да, текст пункта в «configure global security», в котором надо указать порт, к которому будут подключаться агенты, (и указание которого необходимо для появления соответствующего пункта в свойствах агента) тоже переименовали. в [том же коммите](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/c5c803711#diff-459faeca0eeaad7c70ad86b5eb914055).

было: `TCP port for JNLP agents`
стало: `TCP port for inbound agents`